# Why doesn't Ubuntu One sync sub-folders?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu-one to sync my folders. I am experiencing this problem for a while now and its very annoying. A folder within a folder is not synced!

Example:

- "Folder 1" -> synced fine
- now I add "Folder 2" into this folder, but Ubuntu One does not sync it.
- So I have to select with right and add it to Ubuntu One "manually"...

So instead of having:

- /Folder1/
- /Folderx/

I get in my Ubuntu One account:

- Folder1/
- Folder1/Folder1.2
- Folder1/Folder1.3
- Folder1/Folder1.4
- Folderx
- Folderx/Folderx.1

...

Any ideas? How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Because of issues like these, I moved to Dropbox, which works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

U1 has trouble with subfolders. They're usually created on the server but files aren't uploaded for some reason. Once the client is restarted (u1sdtool -d && u1sdtool -q && u1sdtool -c) or the session/computer is restarted, upload is resumed correctly and files in subfolders are taken into account. This is an old bug, I am always very careful when uploading before deleting my local copy because of this. Very annoying.